# ssl_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=sslv2/v3 read server hello a unknown protocol rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tried to fix it but to no avail. Please help.

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  # config.assets.debug = true
  # config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 '587',
  domain:               'gmail.com',
  tsl: true,
  user_name:            'email@gmail.com',
  password:             'password',
  authentication:       :plain,
  ssl: true,
  enable_starttls_auto: true ,
  openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
  }
```

Error: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol

when I search on the net, they just add the line "enable_starttls_auto: true, openssl_verify_mode: 'none' " will end in error, but it still did not solve my problem.

Comment: did you get the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this :

```
 ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'heroku.com',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true

 }
```

Comment: If I do so, it will show the error: "Net::ReadTimeout"

Comment: does this work? i also receive an error.  SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol